calling arrow function method of an object from another object doesn't get the "this" from second object
I want to write a code to do the following arrow function has lexical scoping behaviour
const person = {
  age: 30,
  greet: () => console.log('My age: ' + this.age),
  timerGreet() {
    setTimeout(() => console.log('My age: ' + this.age), 1000);
  },
};

person.greet(); // My age: undefined
person.timerGreet(); // My age: 30

So I did so:
const person1 = {
  age: 44,
  greet: () => console.log('My age: ' + this.age),
};

const person2 = {
  age: 99,
  newGreet() {
    person1.greet();
  },
};

person2.newGreet(); // My age undefined

Why like first code, calling person1.greet() inside a method of person2 doesn't have the surronding "this" which should be person2?
